# find a way to kill a task that wont end so next step of batch can run

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that calls a program used for flashing a NAND chip  called sfh_dm36x.exe, due to how it works this program hangs after its initial flashing, doing it manually I hit CTRL+C and then rerun the command at which point it runs again and finishes (this is normal behaviour for some reason)

Currently i call a batch file called "start.bat, this runs a new batch file called "runflash.bat" which starts the flash process, this opens a new CMD windows and runs the program, in the meantime start.bat counts down from 20 and then kills the sfh_dm36x.exe and the newly spawned command window, it then calls a second batch file called runflash1.bat, this second batch file finishes and the flashing ends fine.

```
start "JudRun" "runflash.bat"
timeout /t 20 >nul
taskkill /im  sfh_dm36x.exe /f
taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq JudRun"
cls
timeout /t 2 >nul
start "JudRun" "runflash1.bat"
```

Im looking for some way to turn this into just one batch file, but cant find a way to do it, if i use the following code then it wont progress to the taskkill command as sfh_dm36x.exe hasnt finished.

```
set /P id=Enter Comport used for flashing: 
sfh_DM36x.exe -nandflash -v -p "COM%id%" ubl1_editedByGaucho.img u-boot_modifiedByGaucho.img
taskkill /im  sfh_dm36x.exe /f
set /P id=Enter Comport used for flashing: 
sfh_DM36x.exe -nandflash -v -p "COM%id%" ubl1_editedByGaucho.img u-boot_modifiedByGaucho.img
```

I was thinking of some kind of timer or for next loop, something that would allow the taskkill to be used.
Hope the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

`Batch-file`s are exactly what its name states. `batch`es commands added to a file and run in sequence. so the one command needs to complete before the other command will run.

Currently you are running `sfh_DM36x.exe` and the batch is just waiting for it to terminate so it can run the next line. So you need to start it outside of the current batch window.

```
title "Judrun"
set /P id=Enter Comport used for flashing: 
start "" "sfh_DM36x.exe" -nandflash -v -p "COM%id%" ubl1_editedByGaucho.img u-boot_modifiedByGaucho.img
taskkill /im  sfh_dm36x.exe /f
set /P id=Enter Comport used for flashing: 
start "" "sfh_DM36x.exe" -nandflash -v -p "COM%id%" ubl1_editedByGaucho.img u- boot_modifiedByGaucho.img
```